# Using Generic Methods with a WebService like WCF or ADO.NET Data Services

Tags: wcf, generics, methods, wcf-data-services

Is it possible to use generic methods with WCF or ADO.NET DS?

Or is it possible to create a generic WebService Repository with WCF or ADO.NET DS?

Comment: Do you mean generic as in do everything, or generics as in the .net feature?

Comment: I have different Entities i.e. Customer and Product. 
I do not want to use stuff like this: Customer.GetList(), Product.GetList().
But GetList<Product>() or GetList<Customer>())

I want to avoid redundancy code by using generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "mu".

You're thinking about it wrong.

WCF - or web services in general - is not about exposing methods.  It's about exposing a data or message contract.

Design a service by designing the messages that get exchanged, not the class interface.

---

There are several ways to go about designing the messages:

1. If you have XML tools, and speak XSD, you might want to design an XML Schema for the input and output messages.   Then embbed that into a WSDL, and [use svcutil to generate the WCF stub or proxy](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/24/wsdl-first-development-with-wcf.aspx).
2. If you have a good vision for what the XML should look like, you can just create sample input + output messages, then "Derive" or infer the XSD from those messages using something like [the XSD.exe tool in the .NET SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx).   The inferred XSD is not always exactly what you want - often it is not general enough if you start from a single message.  But it gets you started.  Once you have the XSD, you can go to step 1.  Actually, step 1 and 2 can be iterative.
3. Design the data contract classes [using the DataContract attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) .
4. Same thing, [using the MessageContract attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx).
5. use a tool like WSCF.

There are [other articles on the blogs on MSDN](http://www.bing.com/search?q=+contract+WCF+first+site%3Amsdn.com&form=QBRE3) that describe the approach and go into more details about the above options.

Comment: Can you give a little example of "designing the messages"?

Comment: If I get you right, I have to design a message that can contain a list of Customers or a list of Products. So a message has to been designed that fits to all kind of lists (in my stupid example), right? So background is I want to use a kind of generic repository for avoiding redundance code.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  And that's entirely possible with XSD or with DataContract.